# Can I set up my Ubuntu machine as a proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I have 2 machines connected to a network that provides internet access.

I would like one of the machines, which is running Ubuntu 10.04, to act as an internet proxy for the other machine, which is running Windows.

How would I set this up? Is there a good Ubuntu proxy I can install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I set up my Ubuntu machine as a proxy?

Yes

> How would I set this up?

Set what up? What sort of proxy? An "internet" proxy you say... so internet via SOCKS proxy or internet via HTTP proxy?

> Is there a good Ubuntu proxy I can install?

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). There is a guide for configuring this [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/804-ubuntu-installing-an-http-proxy-server-squid).

Comment: Preferably a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Take a look at Antinat then.

Comment: Please add that to your question @George and you to your answer @taspeotis :-)